# SQL Server Data Tools and partition functions

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a sliding window loading scenario and the partition functions will be changing their boundaries through time.

I have created some partition functions in my SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) database project with some initial boundaries hardcoded.

However, as time goes on and the partition functions' boundaries change, future SSDT database publishes will revert the boundaries to the original ones.

Is there some way to handle this scenario gracefully, possibly by disabling the publishing of the partition functions?

I've tried changing the *Build Action* property of the partition functions in SSDT, from the default `Build`, to `None`, but then the project fails to build due to a missing reference in the depending objects.

Comment: I always said that diff based deployment is fundamentally broken. [Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) is such a vastly superior [deployment metaphor](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/)!

Comment: The **'Ignore index options'** should be set also to avoid SSDT rebuilding your partitioned index each time the deployment is triggered.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem — hope this helps someone else.

To avoid each database publish recreating the partition function, you can check the *Ignore partition schemes* option in the *Advanced Publish Settings* dialog (*Advanced...* button in the Database Publish dialog).

From the description of the option (emphasis mine):

> Specifies whether differences in partition schemes **and functions** should be ignored or updated when you publish to a database.

However, if you have defined a partitioned object (table or index) with page or row compression, although the *Ignore partition schemes* option no longer recreates the partition function, the partitioned object will get recreated anyway.

This happens because the partitioned object gets scripted with the compression defined *per partition*, and since the object has a different number of partitions than it was originally defined, SSDT recreates the object on publish. E.g. (formatted):

```
WITH ( DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE ON PARTITIONS (1)
     , DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE ON PARTITIONS (2)
     , ...
```

In order for this not to happen, you can also check the *Ignore table options* option, in the same *Advanced Publish Settings* dialog — just keep in mind that you will be ignoring other options, such as `ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS` and `ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS` ([reference of table options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979)).

[image: Advanced Publish Settings dialog]

Comment: Google just led me in here. Awesome info, thank you for sharing.

Comment: Note that if you're using the similar dialog in the project properties -> Debug page, changes will be saved to the .sqlproj.user file, BUT only on project unload.

Answer (score 3):

Ouch, that's not a good situation. As far as I know SSDT doesn't support this. The best workaround I can think of is to use a Pre-Deployment script to store the boundaries in a table and then alter the partition function using those values in the Post-Deployment script.

Comment: Ignore my reply here, judging my Gonsalu's reply above I was clearly wrong.